# oAuth:allow mutiple user to use same credential in spring oauth

Tags: spring, oauth

I have a doubt in OAuth.(i.e) Restrict the user to generated an access_token if the user already in session (multiple users concurrently access the OAuth/token with same credentials) or allow multiple users with same credentials. In a couple of days, I analyzed about this issue, but no clear document available. If anybody know please explain me.

1. OAuth allow multiple users use the same credential? How..
2. OAuth allows user to use single credential? How to restrict?